# Owl-carousel move direction (drag + Previous/Next clicks)

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm making a site where the user is supposed to get contents in chunks, much like a short powerpoint presentation where the user can move back and forth between slides containing divs with HTML.

For this, I thought it would be a good idea to use a carousel-like presentation view. I looked into [Owl-carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) and its `afterMove` callback parameter, but I don't see anything in the documentation of how to get the direction of the movement.

In other words, if the user drags left or clicks the Next button, I want to call function `n` if the user drags to the right or clicks the Previous button, I want to call function `p`. Is this possible or should I look into other plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to do the same but only for next/prev click (i don't use dragging).
Since I didn't find any proper way to get the move direction, I overrided the click function to add an informative class :

```
    $(".owl-next").click(function(){
      $('.owl-carousel').addClass('move-next');
    })

    $(".owl-prev").click(function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').addClass('move-prev');
    })
```

Then in the afterMove function :

```
afterMove: function() {
    if( $('.owl-carousel').hasClass('move-next') ) {
          // Click next: your code
          $('.owl-carousel').removeClass('move-next');
    } else if ( $('.owl-carousel').hasClass('move-prev') ) {
          // Click prev: your code
          $('.owl-carousel').removeClass('move-prev');
    }
}
```

May not be the best way to do it, but at least I can get what I want.

Comment: I love it when I get new answers like this to old questions on SO. I'm not working on the project anymore so I can't test your code but it looks good enough to be considered the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

use the **dragDirection** property of the plugin

Comment: It seems like this only handles the drag event (`owl.this.dragDirection` becomes `undefined` on button presses. Do I need to write separate checks for when the user clicks the previous and next buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Use the state property on relatedTarget to get the direction.

```
owl.on("drag.owl.carousel", function (event) {
    console.log(event.relatedTarget.state.direction);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I read on github.com

/******/

```
var owl = $('#your-carousel-selector').data('owlCarousel');

$(document.documentElement).keyup(function(event) {
    // handle cursor keys
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        owl.prev();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        owl.next();
    }
});
```

Comment: In Carousel2 it is different. http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');